# Access Session stored in redis from Socket.IO on a different server

Tags: node.js, session, socket.io

I have a Kraken app which uses Passport and redis as a session store.
On the client, I also use a socket.io connection, based on a different server than my app.

I have set up Redis as a session store on both sides, with the same URL and it seems to work fine (as i don't see an error on the socket server). However, I can't seem to be able to retrieve the session info on the socket side.

At the moment, I have configured Kraken as such :

```
{
   "secret": "SuperSecret",
   "cookie": {
              "path": "/",
              "httpOnly": true,
              "originalMaxAge": 86400,
              "maxAge": 86400
             },
   "proxy": null
 },
```

and the cookie created reflects that on the client (maxAge matches)

Yet on the socket side, I get this :

```
session: 
   { cookie: 
      { path: '/',
        _expires: null,
        originalMaxAge: null,
        httpOnly: true } 
      }
   }
```

I connect to the store via a middleware on the socket side :

```
var sessionMiddleware = session({
    store: new RedisStore(config.redisFront),
    secret: "SuperSecret",
});
io = require('socket.io')(5000);
io.use(function(socket, next) {
    sessionMiddleware(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
});
```

The sessionID in socket.request.sessionID and in res.sessionID are also different. Am I overlooking something or just plain wrong in my approach? Let me know if you need any more info, I'll be happy to provide that.